# Add content type to a taxonomy - Drupal 7

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes

Hello everyone I have content type named contact where I have many fields like name, email, phone, country... and a taxonomy named organization with fields name, acronym and contact. What I try to do is when I create a new term of this taxonomy I have the possibility to add contact. Many thanks in advance

Comment: can you explain it clear so that it will be easy to answer

Answer (score 1):

if I understand it right, you're trying to reference a "contact"-node...

You can use the module "entity reference" (https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) for that.

Comment: Many thanks Devaraj and Laebs. I think "entity reference" give me a begin solution. Now I can liaise the term to the node but the problem is when I open the page of the node I don't have the term of toxonomy. Should I add it ? How can I see the relation between this 2 elements ?hope I'm clear. Cheers

Comment: You have to add an additional field (type = entity reference) to the taxonomy vocabulary. To do this, go to: admin -> structure -> taxonomy -> edit vocabulary -> fields

Comment: many thanks laebs I will try it and come back to you